# LLVM `opt` gives pass error: "Value::~Value(): Assertion `use_empty() && "Uses remain when a value is destroyed!"

Tags: c++, llvm

When I run the LLVM pass below using `opt`, I get the following error message:

```
While deleting: i32 %
Use still stuck around after Def is destroyed:  %indexLoc = alloca i32
opt: /home/nlykkei/llvm/src/lib/IR/Value.cpp:85: virtual llvm::Value::~Value(): Assertion `use_empty() && "Uses remain when a value is destroyed!"' failed.
```

I invoke `opt` as: `opt -load build/flatten/libFlattenPass.so -opCounter loop.rll`.

I follow the example for inserting instructions into BB's in http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#creating-and-inserting-new-instructions.

I don't really see what is wrong with my code? Should I explicitly delete the `AllocaInst` pointer or?

Program:

```
#include "llvm/Pass.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Function.h"
#include "llvm/IR/BasicBlock.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Instructions.h"
#include "llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h"
#include <map>
#include <string>

using namespace llvm;

namespace {
struct CountOp : public FunctionPass {
    std::map<std::string, int> opCounter;
    std::map<std::string, int> bbNameToId;

    static char ID;
    LLVMContext ctx;

    CountOp() : FunctionPass(ID) {}

    virtual bool runOnFunction(Function &F) {

        std::string bbName("bb");
        int bbId = 0;

        errs() << "Function " << F.getName() << '\n';
        for (Function::iterator bb = F.begin(), e = F.end(); bb != e; ++bb) {

            // assign integer ids to BasicBlock's
            if (bb->hasName()) {
                bbNameToId[bb->getName()] = bbId++;
            } else {
                bb->setName(Twine(bbName + std::to_string(bbId)));
                bbNameToId[bb->getName()] = bbId++;
            }

            for (BasicBlock::iterator i = bb->begin(), e = bb->end(); i != e; ++i) {
                if(opCounter.find(i->getOpcodeName()) == opCounter.end()) {
                    opCounter[i->getOpcodeName()] = 1;
                } else {
                    opCounter[i->getOpcodeName()] += 1;
                }
            }
        }

        AllocaInst* pa = new AllocaInst(Type::getInt32Ty(ctx), 0, "indexLoc");
        BasicBlock& firstBB = F.getBasicBlockList().front();
        Instruction& firstInst = firstBB.front();

        pa->insertBefore(&firstInst);

        std::map <std::string, int>::iterator i = opCounter.begin();
        std::map <std::string, int>::iterator e = opCounter.end();

        while (i != e) {
            errs() << i->first << ": " << i->second << "\n";
            i++;
        }

        i = bbNameToId.begin();
        e = bbNameToId.end();

        while (i != e) {
            errs() << i->first << ": " << i->second << "\n";
            i++;
        }

        errs() << "\n";
        opCounter.clear();
        return false;
    }
};
}

char CountOp::ID = 0;
static RegisterPass<CountOp> X("opCounter", "Counts opcodes per functions");
```

Comment: I have 2 comments: 
1) What's the reason for inserting the alloca instruction?
2) I see that you haven't assigned value to ```ctx```. You can use this [function](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Function.html#a2da53ac53516a3f16191f4c8a8eaa3e5) to get context.

Comment: I just want to try to insert some instruction. It doesn't matter which. Can you modify the program, so it works?

Comment: I am not sure of the exact reason for the error but I am sure that you have to get current LLVMContext from function ```F``` and assign it to ```ctx```. So may be try to modify the code for that and see if the error still occurs.

Comment: Just add something like ```LLVMContext& Ctx = F.getContext();```

Comment: Can't do it now, will try later. Have you tried it? Does it works?

Comment: I don't have the environment setup so I can't.